# Activity doesn't detect onTouchListener with viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener

Alright so I did some research on this topic, and many people seem to have this problem with many "solutions" none of which have worked for me...

Goal:
I want my main activity class (hosting 3 fragments with a viewpager), to use an ontouchevent, motionevent being ACTION_DOWN.

Issue:
I've tried using the method onInterceptTouchEvent(Mot..ev); with no luck, for all i know I might be using it incorrectly. Essentially whenever I click my pastBtn nothing returns

My code:
(main activity)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
    pastBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pastBtn);



    mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    mFragments.add(new Past_Fragment());
    mFragments.add(new zGoal_Fragment());
    mFragments.add(new Future_Fragment());

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mPagerAdapter = new FragmentViewer(fm);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);



}

public class FragmentViewer extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public FragmentViewer(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }





}
```

(xml (fragment_container))

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/main_back"
              android:orientation="horizontal"


>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pastBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/past_btn"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_Two"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/past_text"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/todayBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/today_btn"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_Two"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/today_text"
    />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/futureBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/future_btn"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_Two"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/future_text"
    />



</LinearLayout>
```

What is the "proper method" to return on touchevent from an activity using a viewPager, and if using onIntercptTouchEvent(....) is the proper method, why? and how would I implement it, in this case?

Also If I want to return a touchevent in one of my fragments, would I also use this method since viewpager is behind it??

Comment: you can edit your question with your layout xml, then others can suggest other method or approach, to accomplished your need, why you need to return an ontouchevent (ACTION_DOWN)?

Comment: if you return true from your activity's onTouch() that means it is consumed and it will not pass to child views . So return false from onTouch().